# How to replace text in files using Gradle/Groovy functionality

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am trying to work around the problem described in [GRADLE-2293](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2293) where generated files are always updated because a timestamp is written to the Eclipse files located in directory `.settings` by the [Gradle plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) which generates the Eclipse project files.

The files contain a header like this which I would like to remove

```
#
#Fri Mar 27 10:26:55 CET 2015
```

Currently I am using an Exec task to use the external application `sed` to cut out lines starting with '#':

```
task adjustEclipseSettingsFile(type: Exec) {
    executable 'sed'
    args '-i','-e','s/^#.*//g','.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs'
}
eclipseJdt.finalizedBy adjustEclipseSettingsFile
```

however this adds a dependency on operating system binaries that I would like to avoid.

How can I do this simple removal of lines starting with '#' in a Gradle task without calling external tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are really many ways of doing it, the one with `ant` is probably most reliable:

```
task removeLines << {
   ant.replaceregexp(match:'^#.*', replace:'', flags:'g', byline:true) {
      fileset(dir: project.projectDir, includes: 'lol')
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I had to replace rootDir with projectDir to make it work in multi-project setups as well